# How to send images and text messages with Firebase having different xml layout?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

Okay so I can send text messages just like any simple chat app. Now I want to send the images too(afterwards maybe the attachments such as pdf,etc). So the layout for text message and images will be different.

Currently I have one adapter class and the data is received in a recyclerView. Below is my adapter class:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<TextMessage> messageList;
public Context context;

public MessageAdapter(List<TextMessage> messageList){
    this.messageList = messageList;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_text_message,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.Text.setText(messageList.get(position).getMessage());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messageList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    public TextView Text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        Text = mView.findViewById(R.id.textView_message_text);
    }
}
```

}

Now what if I have image layout also? Is there a way to combine the layout? Or to make different layout files along with different model class? How should I proceed with this? I dont want any code. Just the way forward to this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have multiple type of view Holders base on the viewType. You must override getViewType and return view type int let say 1 for videos and 2 for messages (you need to build that logic accodring to data you have in your app) and then in onCreateViewHolder method using viewType varidable you can decide which view holder you want to show

Comment: pleasure bruh :)